# integration payload router issues

Tags: spring-integration

i am trying to configure payload router to route messages to either rabbitmq,ibmq and kafka MOM's. payload will have to be routed to more than one MOM in some cases, here is the code

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "routerChannel", outputChannel = "outputChannel")
public PayloadTypeRouter router(Log message) {
    PayloadTypeRouter router = new PayloadTypeRouter();
    for (Platform platform : new MessageConfig().getConfig(message.getClientKey())) {
        System.out.println("platform type=" + platform.getRouter());
        if (platform.getRouter().equals(BridgeType.Bridge.rabbitmq.toString())) {
            router.setChannelMapping(String.class.getName(), "rabbitChannel");
        } else if (platform.getRouter().equals(BridgeType.Bridge.ibmmq.toString())) {
            router.setChannelMapping(String.class.getName(), "ibmmqChannel");
        } else if (platform.getRouter().equals(BridgeType.Bridge.kafka.toString())) {
            router.setChannelMapping(String.class.getName(), "kafkaChannel");
        }
    }
    return router;
}
```

earlier i had below code which was working fine(sending to individual MOM but not to two at same time)

```
@Router(inputChannel = "routerChannel")
public String route(Log message) {
    log.info("message in the router='{}'", message.getClientKey());
    for (Platform platform : new MessageConfig().getConfig(message.getClientKey())) {
        System.out.println("platform type=" + platform.getRouter());
        if (platform.getRouter().equals(BridgeType.Bridge.rabbitmq.toString())) {
            return "rabbitChannel";
        } else if (platform.getRouter().equals(BridgeType.Bridge.ibmmq.toString())) {
            return "ibmmqChannel";
        } else if (platform.getRouter().equals(BridgeType.Bridge.kafka.toString())) {
            return "kafkaChannel";
        }
    }
    return "errorChannel";
}
```

not sure what i am doing wrong , appreciate any help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>`PayloadTypeRouter` and `MethodInvokingRouter` only support one destination.</strike>

Use a `RecipientListRouter` with `Recipients` with `MessageSelector`s if you want to route to multiple destinations.

Actually, I was wrong; you can simply return `List<String>` from your second example.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong - see the update to my answer;

Comment: great, it worked after changing it to List. how do we achieve with PayloadTypeRouter ?

Comment: It's not possible with `PayloadTypeRouter` because matching payload types is quite complicated - the payload type might be a subclass of one of the mappings; we have to examine all the super classes and interfaces and we decide which is the closest match, hence multiple matches are not allowed. BTW, your first example is not at all valid - it will return a new PTR for each message which is totally wrong. For simple payload type matching, and multiple matches, your second approach is correct.